# JavaScript formatting indentations in wrapped lines

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, formatting, indentation

I'm trying to figure out how to get IntelliJ to indent (using auto-indent and reformat) *if* conditions that wrap lines farther than the start of the "if" in JavaScript files, such that it would be like this:

```
if ($this.hasClass("current-servicer")
    || ($this.hasClass("new-servicer"))) {
```

Instead of:

```
if ($this.hasClass("current-servicer")
|| ($this.hasClass("new-servicer"))) {
```

I've played around with Setting under Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Tabs and Indents, but to no avail yet.

Current settings:
[image]

Comment: It works as expected for me. What value is set for the Continuation indent option in Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript?